# Save the elements of two lists in columns in a file

Tags: python, list, file

I should save in a file the elements of two lists in this way: elements of the list timestamp beside the elements of the list ID. The following code puts the elements of the second list in the same column of the elements of the first list. Is there a way to correct the code?

```
    class Videocamera(object):
        timestamp = []
        ID = []
        error = []
        def __init__(self, num_id):
            self.num_id = num_id
    file = open("Rilevazioni videocamera 1.txt", "w")
    V1 = Videocamera("VC00")
    V1.timestamp = [n for n in range(100)]
    for n in V1.timestamp:
        file.write(str(n))
        file.write("\n")
    for n in range(10):
        V1.ID.append(0)
    for n in range(10):
        V1.ID.append(1)
    for n in range(10):
        V1.ID.append("Pe0000")
    for n in range(10):
        V1.ID.append("Pe0001")
    for n in range(10):
        V1.ID.append(1)
    for n in range(10):
        V1.ID.append("Pe0002")
    for n in range(10):
        V1.ID.append(1)
    for n in range(10):
        V1.ID.append(0)
    for n in range(10):
        V1.ID.append("Pe0001")
    for n in range(10):
        V1.ID.append("Pe0000")
    for n in V1.ID:
        if n != 1:
            V1.error.append(False)
        else:
            V1.error.append(True)
    for n in V1.ID:
        file.write(str(n))
        file.write("\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

The file writer goes by line, not by column. Every time you call 'write', it writes a row. Exiting a loop does not reset any sort of counter to zero.

You should first make your V1.ID list and then iterate over the two lists and write the row with `file.write("{0} {1}".format(timestamp, id))`.

You could probably zip your two lists together (https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#zip) to make the iteration easier.

Since you responded that it doesn't work: Does this not work?

```
class Videocamera(object):
    timestamp = []
    ID = []
    error = []
    def __init__(self, num_id):
        self.num_id = num_id
file = open("Rilevazioni videocamera 1.txt", "w")
V1 = Videocamera("VC00")
for n in range(10):
    V1.ID.append(0)
for n in range(10):
    V1.ID.append(1)
for n in range(10):
    V1.ID.append("Pe0000")
for n in range(10):
    V1.ID.append("Pe0001")
for n in range(10):
    V1.ID.append(1)
for n in range(10):
    V1.ID.append("Pe0002")
for n in range(10):
    V1.ID.append(1)
for n in range(10):
    V1.ID.append(0)
for n in range(10):
    V1.ID.append("Pe0001")
for n in range(10):
    V1.ID.append("Pe0000")
for n in V1.ID:
    if n != 1:
        V1.error.append(False)
    else:
        V1.error.append(True)
V1.timestamp = [n for n in range(100)]

for n in range(len(V1.timestamp)):
    file.write(str(V1.timestamp[n])+" "+str(V1.ID[n]))
    file.write("\n")
```

or, or equivalently `for n in range(100)`. Quick and dirty, but works if this:

```
0 0
1 0
2 0
3 0
4 0
5 0
6 0
7 0
8 0
9 0
10 1
11 1
12 1
13 1
14 1
15 1
16 1
17 1
18 1
19 1
20 Pe0000
21 Pe0000
22 Pe0000
23 Pe0000
24 Pe0000
```

etc...
is your expected output. 
If this is not your expected output, then could you clarify?

Comment: It doesn't work as I want, however, thank you for the answer

Comment: Sorry, I didn't use the code you wrote, it was a little bit different. My bad.

Comment: No worries, my first answer was not clearly written.